# How to Retrive Dropdown list Value from one jsp page to next jsp page address bar

Tags: jsp

How to access Dropdown list values on next page's address bar in JSP
I know how to access from database but don't know how to retrive it to next page address bar

Answer (score 0):

From method="get" we can retrieve the data from drop-down list on next page's address bar.